# How to know the type of the data being sent from task B to task A?

Tags: c, embedded, freertos

So say I have a task (`taskA`) that accepts data from another task (`taskB`). How do I make the `taskA` such that it could accept generic types? `void` arrays aren't allowed so that's not a possibility.

```c
void buff[100];  // not allowed !!

void taskB(void *params)
{
  while(1) {
    xQueueReceive(queueA, buff, portMAX_DELAY);
  }

}

void taskA(void *params) 
{
   char data[] = "something";
   while(1) {
     xQueueSend(queueA, data, portMAX_DELAY);
   }
}
```

Comment: This is just a normal data serialization problem.  The general way to achieve it is to stream your data through an ordinary buffer (usually `unsigned char`), and reserve some bits in your communication protocol that will indicate the actual data type being transmitted.  Then, you can decode the bit stream to extract those values by using whatever decoding method is appropriate for how the sender encoded them.  In the case of integer data, you might just transmit these as raw bytes.

Comment: Not sure why `unsigned char` needs to be used for the buffer to be sent. What if want to send data type of `double`?  and by reserving the data being transmitted in a protocol, you're referring to storing in a struct I reckon?

Comment: No, I'm not referring to using a struct, and you don't seem to understand the fundamentals here.  You just need to deliver BYTES.  How you choose to REPRESENT data in those bytes is up to you.  You can put a `double` value into a byte stream, either as raw bytes or encoded somehow or as text or whatever you wish.  The point is that the receiver needs to know that the next X bytes will contain a `double` value and then decode it correctly from the data it receives, hence why you add that information to the byte stream.

Comment: so you're saying the idea is to send data bytes whereas the receiver should know what data type is being sent? but how does the receiver know about the data being sent if the sender task doesn't pass a struct with a data type?

Comment: Some of the bytes you send provide information about what data types you are sending.  So when the receiver gets that information, it knows what to do.  I'm telling you this repeatedly and I'm not sure why it's not sinking in.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

Answer (score 0):

One option is using a "byte-array" (ex. `unsigned char` array) and copy from/to it whatever data you need (taking care of not introducing undefined behavior). You can use the first byte(s) to know what kind of data you have sent.

Another is using a `union` inside a `struct` with an additional variable (in the `struct`) that holds a "tag" that tells you which kind of data you have in the `union`.

Both are essentially the same.

Comment: `unsigned char` in `taskB`?

Comment: In whatever buffer you use to receive/send data.

Comment: regarding your second option, you mean `taskA` sends a struct instead of a mere array with the type of data being among the struct members which would be used in decoding in `taskB`?

Comment: Yeah, one way or another, you have to send something that allows you to know in the receiver what type you sent.

Comment: why `unsigned char` in particular?

Comment: Because it is the closest to a "raw byte without further meaning" that C has. C++ has a `byte` type nowadays.

Comment: um, what if the user sends in data of type `double`?

Comment: also, do you have an example to get around with a union in a struct? what i'm thinking of defining `enum` with possible types, and have one struct member that the application will initialize to any of the enum members for the type

Comment: 'um, what if the user sends in data of type double', it must not - you forbid it with your comms protocol.  It could, say, send an unsigned char that indicates 'double follows', followed by the double. You MUST define a protocol and ensure that both ends follow it!

Answer (score 0):

If the type is susceptible to change frequently (b/w different calls), a simple approach is, adding type data to the function decoration, like;

```
typedef enum {enumInt, enumDbl, enumChr, ... <add other types>} TypeInfo;

void taskB(void *ptr, TypeInfo t) {
    switch (t) {
        case enumInt:
            int *p = (int *)ptr;
            // do stuff as if data is integer
            break;
        case enumDbl:
            double *p = (double *)ptr;
            // do stuff as if data is double
            break;
        case enumChr:
            char *p = (char *)ptr;
            // do stuff as if data is char
            break;
    }
}

void taskA(void *ptr, TypeInfo t) {
    ...
    taskB(ptr, t);
    ...
}
```

Comment: is it convenient to hardcode all the types in the enum though? what if you miss any?

Comment: @xyf : Yes, you're right if there are too many types, especially non-standart types like `struct`s, etc... That `switch` or `if` block will be a mess.

Comment: not sure if this would work in my case though cause `taskA` would write to a queue that `taskB` would read off of and it's not like calling a function. Task is referring to a thread

Comment: @xyf If you have that many types and that level of abstraction in an embedded RTOS system, I'd say that something is off with your overall program design. These systems should be deterministic, not randomly generic.

Comment: i'm making sort of a library where which could be used in different applications that want to send data wirelessly. @Lundin

Comment: @xyf Then work with raw `uint8_t` byte streams. You just need an enum, a data pointer and optionally a size variable.

Comment: I understand a bit of it but not the entire picture. byte streams are of type `uint8_t` so you have a buffer with the specific size allocated, but how does the receiver parse, say, `double` which is being sent from the byte streams? do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

See the following example with well-commented.

You can edit the `xMessage` struct to store any data that you want to send/receive.

This example also sends the message in 2 ways: send the address of the allocated buffer and send the value of buffer. You have to consider which way subtable with your program.

Note that the item is received by copy so a buffer of adequate size must be provided. The number of bytes copied into the buffer was defined when the queue was created.

Ref: https://www.freertos.org/a00118.html

```c
/* Define a variable of type struct AMMessage.  The examples below demonstrate
how to pass the whole variable through the queue, and as the structure is
moderately large, also how to pass a reference to the variable through a queue. */
struct AMessage
{
   char ucMessageID;
   char ucData[ 20 ];
} xMessage;

/* Queue used to send and receive complete struct AMessage structures. */
QueueHandle_t xStructQueue = NULL;

/* Queue used to send and receive pointers to struct AMessage structures. */
QueueHandle_t xPointerQueue = NULL;


void vCreateQueues( void )
{
   xMessage.ucMessageID = 0xab;
   memset( &( xMessage.ucData ), 0x12, 20 );

   /* Create the queue used to send complete struct AMessage structures.  This can
   also be created after the schedule starts, but care must be task to ensure
   nothing uses the queue until after it has been created. */
   xStructQueue = xQueueCreate(
                         /* The number of items the queue can hold. */
                         10,
                         /* Size of each item is big enough to hold the
                         whole structure. */
                         sizeof( xMessage ) );

   /* Create the queue used to send pointers to struct AMessage structures. */
   xPointerQueue = xQueueCreate(
                         /* The number of items the queue can hold. */
                         10,
                         /* Size of each item is big enough to hold only a
                         pointer. */
                         sizeof( &xMessage ) );

   if( ( xStructQueue == NULL ) || ( xPointerQueue == NULL ) )
   {
      /* One or more queues were not created successfully as there was not enough
      heap memory available.  Handle the error here.  Queues can also be created
      statically. */
   }
}

/* Task that writes to the queues. */
void vATask( void *pvParameters )
{
struct AMessage *pxPointerToxMessage;

   /* Send the entire structure to the queue created to hold 10 structures. */
   xQueueSend( /* The handle of the queue. */
               xStructQueue,
               /* The address of the xMessage variable.  sizeof( struct AMessage )
               bytes are copied from here into the queue. */
               ( void * ) &xMessage,
               /* Block time of 0 says don't block if the queue is already full.
               Check the value returned by xQueueSend() to know if the message
               was sent to the queue successfully. */
               ( TickType_t ) 0 );

   /* Store the address of the xMessage variable in a pointer variable. */
   pxPointerToxMessage = &xMessage;

   /* Send the address of xMessage to the queue created to hold 10    pointers. */
   xQueueSend( /* The handle of the queue. */
               xPointerQueue,
               /* The address of the variable that holds the address of xMessage.
               sizeof( &xMessage ) bytes are copied from here into the queue. As the
               variable holds the address of xMessage it is the address of xMessage
               that is copied into the queue. */
               ( void * ) &pxPointerToxMessage,
               ( TickType_t ) 0 );

   /* ... Rest of task code goes here. */
}

/* Task that reads from the queues. */
void vADifferentTask( void *pvParameters )
{
struct AMessage xRxedStructure, *pxRxedPointer;

   if( xStructQueue != NULL )
   {
      /* Receive a message from the created queue to hold complex struct AMessage
      structure.  Block for 10 ticks if a message is not immediately available.
      The value is read into a struct AMessage variable, so after calling
      xQueueReceive() xRxedStructure will hold a copy of xMessage. */
      if( xQueueReceive( xStructQueue,
                         &( xRxedStructure ),
                         ( TickType_t ) 10 ) == pdPASS )
      {
         /* xRxedStructure now contains a copy of xMessage. */
      }
   }

   if( xPointerQueue != NULL )
   {
      /* Receive a message from the created queue to hold pointers.  Block for 10
      ticks if a message is not immediately available.  The value is read into a
      pointer variable, and as the value received is the address of the xMessage
      variable, after this call pxRxedPointer will point to xMessage. */
      if( xQueueReceive( xPointerQueue,
                         &( pxRxedPointer ),
                         ( TickType_t ) 10 ) == pdPASS )
      {
         /* *pxRxedPointer now points to xMessage. */
      }
   }

   /* ... Rest of task code goes here. */
}
```

Comment: right, so you're using the same struct type on both ends so that's fine, but why using `char` for that data being sent in particular (`ucData`)? what if you want to send data of type `double`?

Comment: Everything can be treated as byte-array, so you can define the `ucData` as `unsigned char*`, and if you want to send an array of double you can use as `ucData = unsigned char*) double_array;`, but in this case, you have to dynamically allocate the array pointed by `ucData` and send by address via the queue. The receive queue also take the responsibility of free the `ucData`.

Comment: why dynamically allocate `ucData`? and does casting from `double` to `unsigned char` even work though?

Comment: If your data is not determined in advance, you have to dynamically allocate the buffer.
[xyf] and does casting from double to unsigned char even work though?
Yes, if not, the compiler will show the warning

Comment: i'm not sure if i'm getting your point then: https://onlinegdb.com/r1ef5YBZQP

Comment: Let's see bro @xyf: https://onlinegdb.com/SkYA6mzXD